# Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Thinkpad T430 with Nvidia GF108M [NVS 5400M] graphics broke Nouveau driver & Wayland

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, thinkpad, wayland, nouveau

When I upgraded to from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, it resulted in a fatal error splash screen before getting to the login manager.

I had been running the Nouveau driver & Wayland (SwayWM, sometimes Gnome) without any issues on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I was able to get my system semi-functional by dropping to a virtual console with Ctrl+Alt+f3 and installing the `nvidia-driver-390` using the `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command (sudo apt install `nvidia-driver-390` also worked.)

However, the Nouveau driver or Wayland remain broken. (`nvidia-driver-390` will only drive a 4k display at 30Hz; and Sway, Studio One, and other parts of my config only work with Wayland.)

I have tried:

```
sudo apt purge *nvidia*
```

But that results in a broken system. I have also tried installing, removing, purging, and/or re-installing other packages (including ubuntu-desktop) without effect.

Running `startx` fails with errors, including:

`xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)`...

`MESA-LOADER: failed to open crocus: /usr/lib/dri/crocus_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)` (there are a bunch of these, for crocus, zink, kms_swrast, swrast. I checked and the files being looked for seem to exist in the expected location.)

`couldn't get display device`...

`xinit: connection to X server lost`...

I installed LightDM, and managed to get Wayland to show up in the menu, but when I log-in, goes back to the login screen.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try "recovery" mode from the grub menu?  Without the nvidia drivers, you probably need the "nomodeset" keyword on the grub kernel line (like recovery mode has).

Comment: Thank you ubfan1. I have not. But I did edit the grub config (`/etc/default/grub`) to include `nomodeset` (changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`), and then updated grub (`sudo update-grub`) and initramfs (`sudo update-initramfs -u`).

Comment: @ubfan1 I tried booting into recovery mode, but it didn't help. I also tried an old kernel that was lying around (5.15.x instead of 6.x, as I recall?), which didn’t help either.